# Advanced Ordering Or Grouping Of Query Results (having?), Access 2013

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, ms-access-2013, having

I REALLY need help.

I have a list of faculty members that can either be in assigned to a department or just affiliated with the department.
I am trying to query but order the results so that any faculty that appear in the specified department appear in the list first, while anyone affiliated with the specified department are at the bottom of the queried results.

I want the affiliated faculty to be at the bottom of the query results!

Here is my example:
I am querying Philosophy, 20 faculty members are displayed, alphabetically but in no particular order and the results include ANYONE who has Philosophy in Dept 1 or Dept 2 of their record AND anyone who is simply Affiliated with the department. Some are in the actual department (Dept 1 or Dept 2 fields) but others are just affiliated with the department (Affiliation 1 - 5 fields) all interdispersed.

Now I want the query results to be ordered to show: faculty who have DEPT 1 or DEPT 2 = Philosophy, and any faculty that have Affiliations = Philosophy to be at the bottom of the list by themselves.

How do I do this? I've tried Order By and Having, I've tried Group By... Nothing seems to work the way I want it to.. I don't think I am using the write code.
Please, please help me. I've been stuck on this for hours.

Please help - here's my query code:

```
    SELECT listOfAllFaculty.[ID], listOfAllFaculty.[lastName], listOfAllFaculty.[firstName], listOfAllFaculty.[middleInitialMiddleName], listOfAllFaculty.[position], listOfAllFaculty.[emeritusPosition], listOfAllFaculty.[department1], listOfAllFaculty.[department2], listOfAllFaculty.[school1], listOfAllFaculty.[school2], listOfAllFaculty.[affiliation1], listOfAllFaculty.[affiliation2], listOfAllFaculty.[affiliation3], listOfAllFaculty.[affiliation4], listOfAllFaculty.[affiliation5], listOfAllFaculty.[degree], listOfAllFaculty.[specialty], listOfAllFaculty.[awards], listOfAllFaculty.[other]
FROM listOfAllFaculty
WHERE (((listOfAllFaculty.department1)=[Type Department1])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.department2)=[Type Department2])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation1)=[Type Affiliation1])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation2)=[Type Affiliation2])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation3)=[Type Affiliation3])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation4)=[Type Affiliation4])) Or (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation5)=[Type Affiliation5]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for using `iif` in your `order by` clause:

```
SELECT listOfAllFaculty.[ID], listOfAllFaculty.[lastName], ...
FROM listOfAllFaculty
WHERE (((listOfAllFaculty.department1)=[Type Department1])) Or    
    (((listOfAllFaculty.department2)=[Type Department2])) Or 
    (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation1)=[Type Affiliation1])) Or
     (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation2)=[Type Affiliation2])) Or
     (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation3)=[Type Affiliation3])) Or
     (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation4)=[Type Affiliation4])) Or
     (((listOfAllFaculty.affiliation5)=[Type Affiliation5]))
ORDER BY 
    IIF(listOfAllFaculty.department1=[Type Department1],0,
        IIF(listOfAllFaculty.department2=[Type Department2],0,1))
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I do have a question, if I want to do what you've done but then alphabetize by last name how can I do it? I tried the built in sort by, but then it ruined the above ordering.

Comment: Just add it to the end of the `order by` clause -- `order by iif(...), listOfAllFaculty.[lastName]`.